# CloudKit and Core sync data between devices

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

I created a simple `Notes` app based on `Core data`. Now i want add sync between user devices.

And  all  articles that i read ([this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/134694/cloudkit-tutorial-getting-started), [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-cloudkit--cms-23775)) said that i should fully get rid of my core data database, and all my code will lost and rework all with `ICloud kit`?

The is no way to sync data from `Core Data` to `ICloud` ? And if i get rid of core data, how my app will work offline ?

And please suggest good simple projects with `ICloud` sync

P.S. I googled about an hour. Icloud is deprecated so do sync with it is not recommended. I confused. How now i can sync data between devices??

Comment: can check one of this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kG3ujYzwv0
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesignForCoreDataIniCloud.html

Comment: @SatishMavani yes i saw it, but it is on obj c:( and it is hard to convert it...

Answer (score 1):

Core Data used to have iCloud syncing, but it has been deprecated as of iOS 10. It had several problems, sometimes major.

Apple now has something called CloudKit, which is not the same thing. You can use CloudKit to sync data between devices. But **this does not mean that you should drop Core Data**.  CloudKit only syncs; it is not a replacement for having your app save data on the device, it's only a way to send data to other devices. If you're using CloudKit, you also need to use some other way to store data on the local device.

Also, it's "CloudKit". Not "ICloud Kit". I don't know why, but it's important to get the names right.

Comment: Thank you. But is there any examples how to use  `CloudKit` with 'Core data' objects for sync. Because i don't understand. For example i have obect Person. I send it to cloud with some `CloudKit` function. Then on other device that doesn't have internet access i created 3 Persons. Then how do i sync all this data?  `Icloud` do this with some magic. I don't know how.

Comment: I don't think **any** sync mechanism will send data to a device that, as you say "doesn't have internet access". How do you expect to get any data into or out of that device?

Comment: No, i mean when device will  connect to internet. It should sync local data.

Comment: Apple provides [a sample CloudKit app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CloudAtlas/Introduction/Intro.html) as well as [detailed, extensive CloudKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html). If that's not enough, they provide [even more detailed documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit).